# Expanding data frame between dates

Tags: r, date, data.table

I've been trying to use the data.table library to expand a set of dates, but I keep getting the following error:

'from' must be of length 1

date_df

| transaction_id | start_date | end_date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1-5-2023 | 1-10-2023 |
| 2 | 2-3-2023 | 2-10-2023 |

i'm trying to get it into the following data frame:

| transaction_id | start_date | end_date | current_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1-5-2023 | 1-10-2023 | 1-5-2023 |
| 1 | 1-5-2023 | 1-10-2023 | 1-6-2023 |
| 1 | 1-5-2023 | 1-10-2023 | 1-7-2023 |
| 1 | 1-5-2023 | 1-10-2023 | 1-8-2023 |
| 1 | 1-5-2023 | 1-10-2023 | 1-9-2023 |
| 1 | 1-5-2023 | 1-10-2023 | 1-10-2023 |
| 2 | 2-3-2023 | 2-10-2023 | 2-3-2023 |
| 2 | 2-3-2023 | 2-10-2023 | 2-4-2023 |
| 2 | 2-3-2023 | 2-10-2023 | 2-5-2023 |
| 2 | 2-3-2023 | 2-10-2023 | 2-6-2023 |
| 2 | 2-3-2023 | 2-10-2023 | 2-7-2023 |
| 2 | 2-3-2023 | 2-10-2023 | 2-8-2023 |
| 2 | 2-3-2023 | 2-10-2023 | 2-9-2023 |
| 2 | 2-3-2023 | 2-10-2023 | 2-10-2023 |

I used the following code:

```
setDT(orig_df)[, list(date = seq(from = orig_df$start_date, to = orig_df$end_Date, by = 'day')), by = transaction_id]
```

The code works when I use a single record, but I can't use the seq function for multiple records.

I've seen questions like this in other threads but the solutions from those threads don't seem to work and result in the error shown above.

Comment: `seq` doesn't work that way, you can't start from two different dates. See e.g. `seq(from = 1:2, to = 3:4)`.

Comment: Perhaps you want just `date_df[, list(date = seq(from = start_date, to = end_date, by = 'day')), by = transaction_id]` ?

Comment: I've tried this solution but I'm getting the same error

Comment: Are you sure your dates are not strings? You do not provide your data, just tabular, but there it looks like a mdy formatted string.